# getting null data on first load in react redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello all I need help I am getting null data in redux toolkit on first load in console below is my full code

---profileSlice---

```
export const profileSlice = createSlice({
    name: "profile",
    initialState : { value: null },
    reducers: {
        profileAction : (state, action) => {
           state.value = action.payload
        }
    },
});

export const { profileAction} = profileSlice.actions;

export default profileSlice.reducer;
```

---Action---

```
export const fetchProfile = (token,path) => async (dispatch) => {
    
         await axios.get(Constants.url + path,
            {
                headers : {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json', 
                    'Accept': "application/json",
                    'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
        )
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
              type:'profile/profileAction',
              payload:res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        })
}
```

---profile component---

```
import {fetchProfile} from '../Redux/actions';

const [basicInformation, setbasicInformation] = useState({
    name: '', 
    email: ''
})
const response = useSelector((state) => state.profile.value);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProfile('token','path'))
    setbasicInformation({
        name:response.name,
        email:response.email,
    })
    console.log(response);
  }, [])
console.log(basicInformation);
```

I am getting null value on both response and basicInformation State on (first load or after login)  after I refresh the page I got that data can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal - your `useEffect` only runs after the component has rendered and already encountered the `null`. You will have to check `if` the value from state is `null` and render some kind of loading indicator.

Comment: I got the data i solved by using 2 useEffect first for dispatch second for getting data

Comment: Yes and before the data is "there" it is `null`. React renders nonetheless. You cannot warp the rules of time and space - before data is there, it is not there, so you have to handle that case in your code.